# Is there a way to get google's description through JSON?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-custom-search, urlfetch

I got the following code which is based on google api calls. What it currently returns is title + URL. What I am trying to get is the description of a linkedin page, and split the information in it by ';'. Is there a command for it?

I see there is for getting the URL and TITLE, but I couldn't find in documentation a way to scrape the description:

```
function getSize(companyName) {

var key="AIzaSyDoZfj4VJPgyYvPbUg6fbObcueAkGxyR-U"
let search = "site:linkedin.com/company "+" "+companyName+" company size"
let searchEngineId = "a480fef134d0c4c6f"

// Call Google Custom Search API
var options = {
  'method' : 'get',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
};
response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="+key+"&q="+search+"&cx="+searchEngineId, options);

// Parse linkedin URL and Name
//let url = JSON.parse(response).items[0].formattedUrl
let title = JSON.parse(response).items[0].title.split("-")[1]


// display the results in 2 columns
var results = new Array(1);
let info = new Array(2);
//info[0]=url
info[1]=description
results=info[1]

return results
```

Comment: the `pagemap` field contains the `items[0].pagemap.metatags[0]["og:description"]` , perhaps that would help!

Comment: Hey @RavikumarRajendran, thanks. This helps me get the description of the linkedin page, for example when running this: `
let search = "site:linkedin.com/company/"+" "+companyName+" company size" `
the method you shared helps me get the description of the company. What I try to scrape is company size out of the google desc. Any way for that?

Comment: perhaps you could use regex expression to extract the numbers from the given string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking out the output of the custom search with your parameters, the company size is included under `items[0].snippet`:

```js
"items":[
   {
      "kind":"customsearch#result",
      "title":"Twitter | LinkedIn",
      "link":"https://www.linkedin.com/company/twitter",
      "snippet":"Website: https://careers.twitter.com. Industries: Software Development. Company size: 5,001-10,000 employees. Headquarters: San Francisco, CA."
      //...etc
```

As you can see it's just plaintext and it's not under any metatags, so your best bet is to use a regex to extract the number as suggested in the comments.

```
response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="+key+"&q="+search+"&cx="+searchEngineId, options);

var snippet = JSON.parse(response).items[0].snippet
var regex = new RegExp(/(?<=Company size: ).*?(?= employees)/);
var size = regex.exec(snippet)[0]
```

The value of `size` is `5,001-10,000`, extracted from the snippet above. The regex `/(?<=Company size: ).*?(?= employees)/` just looks for the value between "Company size:" and "employees".

You'll probably have to do something like this if you want to extract anything that's not in its own tag, be wary of handling cases where the company size is not in the snippet. You can also check the full response in something like [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to have a better idea of what the structure of the response looks like.

##### Reference:

- [Search object definition](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/Search)